# How would I control a JCarousel inside another JCarousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

Using JCarousel I currently have a carousel inside another carousel, which I can trigger to start playing slides by clicking on a play button that I created on the outside carousel. These are all loaded dynamically.

I'd like to have the inner carousel stop animating and go back to it's original loaded position when I click to change the slide of the outer carousel.

```
Here is what I have currently for manipulating JCarousel:
//outer carousel
$('#carousel').jcarousel({
    auto: 0,
    wrap: 'circular',
    scroll: 1,
    initCallback: carousel_initCallBack,
    itemVisibleInCallback: {
        onBeforeAnimation:  gallerycarousel_itemfirst
}

// Info Box

$('.info').click(function() {
    var itemid = $(this).attr('id').substring(5);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/get_case_studies.php?item=' + itemid,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var infobox = $('#box_info' + data.data[0].id)
            infobox.html('');
                var content = '<div class="main_sec">'+data.data[0].main_desc+'</div><div class="sec_sec">'+data.data[0].sec_desc+'</div><div class="visit"><span class="box_num"><img src="img/visitor.png" alt="#" /> Visitors:</span>'+data.data[0].visitors+'</div><div class="avg"><span class="box_num"><img src="img/time.png" alt="#"/> Average time on site:</span>'+ data.data[0].avg_time +'</div><a href="'+ data.data[0].url +'" target="_blank" class="link"></a>';
                infobox.append(content);
            $('.box_info').animate({left: '0px'}, 200);
        }
    });     
});

function carousel_initCallBack(carousel) {
    carousel.clip.hover(function() {
        $('.gallery_control').stop().animate({"top": "454px"}, 200);
        carousel.stopAuto();
    }, function() {
        $('.gallery_control').stop().animate({"top": "524px"}, 200);
        $('.box_info').animate({left: '-302px'}, 200 );
        carousel.startAuto();
    });

    $('#gallerycarousel_controls .btn_right').click(function() {
        carousel.next();
        return false;
    });

    $('#gallerycarousel_controls .btn_left').click(function() {
        carousel.prev();
        return false;
    });

    $('.grid').click(function() {
        $('.gallery_control').animate({"top": "524px"}, 200);
        $('#grid_view').fadeIn('slow');
        carousel.stopAuto();
        $('#grid_view').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
        carousel.startAuto();
        });
    });

     $('#carousel_slides .btn_item').click(function() {
        carousel.scroll($.jcarousel.intval($(this).attr('id')));
        $('#grid_view').fadeOut('slow');
        $('.gallery_control').animate({"top": "454px"}, 200);
        return false;
    });

    //this is the play button which generates and starts the inner carousel
    $('.play').click(function() {
        var itemid = $(this).attr('id').substring(5);
        $('#int_carousel' + itemid).load('get_slideshow.php?slideshow&item=' + itemid, function() {
            $('#int_carousel' + itemid).jcarousel({
                auto: 3,
                wrap: 'circular',
                scroll: 1
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I have tried adding a click function within the 'carousel_initCallBack' function to see if I can control the inner carousel like this:

```
 $('#gallerycarousel_controls .btn_right').click(function() {
        $('#int_carousel' + itemid).stopAuto(); 
    });
```

The above doesn't work as I have tried and this would probably not bring the inner carousel back to the original position of the slide.

I have went on multiple different forums and have been searching everywhere I could on the internet and I am still not able to find any solid help or assistance. I am in dire need of assistance on this as I ran out of options. Please if someone can help me, I'd appreciate it so much. I am still new to web development and need guidance.

Comment: Great Scott! you could be breaking the space-time continuum!

Comment: Carouselception sounds like a bad idea. Assuming they're all horizontal or all vertical.